# Proof that two antiderivatives differ by a constant, quantifier confusion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The proof that two antiderivatives of $f$ differ by a constant is given in several other questions.

By the mean value theorem, for all $a<b\in I$, there exists an $x\in[a,b]$ such that
$$
(F - G)^\prime (x)  = \frac{(F-G)(b) - (F-G)(a)}{b-a} \\
 = F^\prime(x) - G^\prime(x) \\
= f(x) - f(x) \\
= 0 \\
\implies 0 = \frac{(F-G)(b) - (F-G)(a)}{b-a} \\
\implies (F-G)(b) = (F-G)(a) \\
\implies F(b) - G(b) = F(a) - G(a) 
$$

so we can define

$$
C := F(b) - G(b) = F(a) - G(a) 
$$
QED.

But since that's true for *all* $a$ and $b$, what happens if we let $a=\inf I$? Then $$F(a)=G(a)=0,$$ which means that $$F(b)=G(b)$$ for all $b>\inf I$. But that doesn't seem like it's true.

So I suspect I'm confused about quantifiers somewhere. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why should $F(a)=G(a)=0$ when $a=\inf I$?

Comment: @egreg When $a=\inf I$ is the left-hand side of the interval, and the integral at that point is always 0, because the width of the integral is 0, no?

Comment: Integrals? Do you see them here?

Comment: @egreg Oh I see. Antiderivatives are just functions. They needn't be 0 at any particular place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function on the interval $I$ and $p\in I$, then
$$
F(x)=\int_p^x f(t)\,dt
$$
is *an* antiderivative of $f$. Similarly, if $q\in I$, then
$$
G(x)=\int_q^x f(t)\,dt
$$
There is no reason why at *any* point $a\in I$ it holds that $F(a)=G(a)=0$.

Also, antiderivatives need not be of the above form. Just to make a simple example, if $f$ is the constant zero function, then $\int_p^x f(t)\,dt$ is the constant zero function for every $p$, but any constant is an antiderivative.

You are misguided by the context. More generally, without reference to antiderivatives,

> if $H$ is a differentiable function on the interval $I$ and $H'$ is the constant zero function, then $H$ is constant.

*Proof.* Let $a,b\in I$, with $a<b$. By the mean value theorem there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $H(b)-H(a)=(b-a)H'(c)=0$. Thus $H(a)=H(b)$. Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, we have that $H(x)=H(a)$, for every $x\in I$.